# Mocking a function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing

i try to figure how to mock a function in a helper.py that use in several methods for a unit test.

I try with patch, @patch('project.helpers.function_0', new=lambda: True) but didn't work.

How is the correct way to do this?

Thank you.

---

### Update

I have 1 function and 1 decorator that i need to override for all test set.

helpers.py

```
def myfunction(asd):
    # ...
    return asd
```

decorators.py

```
def mydecorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def _wrapped_func(asd, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        return func(asd, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_func
```

### How i resolved

***I want to know how do this with mock, thank you!***

test_base.py

```
import project.decorators
import project.helpers

def myfunction_mock(asd):
   # ...
   return asd
helpers.myfunction = myfunction_mock

def mydecorator_mock(func):
   # ...
decorators.mydecorator = mydecorator_mock
```

Comment: The keyword argument you're looking for is `new_callable`, not `new`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, this way give and extra arg in the test, i need override the function for all the test. The function_0 is called in other methods i call...

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please update your question with your testcase code and describe the unexpected behavior and desired behavior.

Comment: @sytech update with more data the question, thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some key things going on here.

1. If possible, you should be using `unittest.mock` (or `mock` installed via `pip`).
2. You are likely patching in the wrong location.
3. When using `mock.patch` you probably want to use the `new_callable` keyword argument, rather than `new`

Suppose your production code looks something like this....

```
#production_module.py
from helpers import myfunction

def some_function(a):
    result = myfunction(a) + 1
    return result
```

If you wanted to test `some_function` from your production code, mocking `myfunction` your test code should patch `production_module.myfunction` not `helpers.myfunction`

So your test code may look like this

```
import mock
from production_module import some_function

def mock_myfunction(*args, **kwargs):
    return 1

@mock.patch('production_module.myfunction', new_callable=mock_myfunction)
def test_some_function(mock_func):
    result = some_function(1) # call the production function
    assert mock_func.called # make sure the mock was actually used
    assert result == 2
```

Another way of using `mock.patch` is as a context manager. So the patch will only apply in that context.

```
with mock.patch(...) as mock_func:
    some_function(1) # mock_func is called here

some_function(1) # the mock is no longer in place here
```